# Vertically center textwidth table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Sorry for this question but I'm new using LaTeX. I have a table which width is set to be `\textwidth` using `tabularx{\textwidth}` and one of its rows will have 3 or 4 lines. This is my current code:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}
    \begin{table}[b!] % hbtp
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | c | X }
            \arrayrulecolor{black} 
            \hline
            \textbf{$e_\#$} & \textbf{Time interval} & \textbf{Topic} \\ 
            \hline
            \arrayrulecolor{gray}
            1 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 20:30:05 \\ To: 2019-04-15 21:30:05} & \textbf{díamundialdelarte, 15deabril:} enfocat(0.94), meningitis(0.94), construyendolarepública(0.94), 14deabril(0.68), ley(0.66), españa(0.62)  \\
            \hline
            2 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 09:00:05 \\ To: 2019-04-15 17:00:05} & \textbf{gracias:} semana(0.61), muchísimas(0.64) \\
            \hline
            3 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 19:30:05 \\ To: 2019-04-16 01:00:05} & \textbf{notre:} dame(0.98), catedral(0.92), incendio(0.76), parís(0.91), historia(0.73), humanidad(0.77), llamas(0.74), paris(0.64), tristeza(0.65)  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{April 15th 2019 top 3 events}
        \label{tab:mabed-impact}
    \end{table}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
```

and this is its visualization:

[image: Table visualization]

I would like that:

- All the cells were vertically centered
- Columns 1 and 2 were horizontally centered
- Column 3 were horizontally left aligned, but its header (row 1) were horizontally centered

How can achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c c >{\RaggedRight}X }
            \toprule
            \textbf{$e_\#$} & \textbf{Time interval} & \makecell[cc]{\textbf{Topic}} \\ 
            \midrule
            1 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l} From & 2019-04-15 20:30:05 \\ To & 2019-04-15 21:30:05\end{tabular} & \textbf{díamundialdelarte, 15deabril:} enfocat(0.94), meningitis(0.94), construyendolarepública(0.94), 14deabril(0.68), ley(0.66), españa(0.62)  \\\addlinespace

            2 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l}From& 2019-04-15 09:00:05 \\ To & 2019-04-15 17:00:05\end{tabular} & \textbf{gracias:} semana(0.61), muchísimas(0.64) \\ \addlinespace
            3 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l}From & 2019-04-15 19:30:05 \\ To & 2019-04-16 01:00:05 \end{tabular} & \textbf{notre:} dame(0.98), catedral(0.92), incendio(0.76), parís(0.91), historia(0.73), humanidad(0.77), llamas(0.74), paris(0.64), tristeza(0.65)  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{April 15th 2019 top 3 events}
        \label{tab:mabed-impact}
    \end{table}
```

[image: Update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the `tabularx` `X` type column to be vertically centered using `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`. With the `makecelll` package that you already use, you can also change the horizontal (and vertical) alignment of a single cell. Combining these, you can achieve the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}


    \begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | c | X }
            \arrayrulecolor{black} 
            \hline
            \textbf{$e_\#$} & \textbf{Time interval} & \makecell[cc]{\textbf{Topic}} \\ 
            \hline
            \arrayrulecolor{gray}
            1 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 20:30:05 \\ To: 2019-04-15 21:30:05} & \textbf{díamundialdelarte, 15deabril:} enfocat(0.94), meningitis(0.94), construyendolarepública(0.94), 14deabril(0.68), ley(0.66), españa(0.62)  \\
            \hline
            2 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 09:00:05 \\ To: 2019-04-15 17:00:05} & \textbf{gracias:} semana(0.61), muchísimas(0.64) \\
            \hline
            3 & \makecell{From: 2019-04-15 19:30:05 \\ To: 2019-04-16 01:00:05} & \textbf{notre:} dame(0.98), catedral(0.92), incendio(0.76), parís(0.91), historia(0.73), humanidad(0.77), llamas(0.74), paris(0.64), tristeza(0.65)  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{April 15th 2019 top 3 events}
        \label{tab:mabed-impact}
    \end{table}


    \end{document}
```

Personally, I would suggest a slightly different design (less horizontal and no vertical lines, aligning th `:` in the second column):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c  c  X }
            \toprule
            \textbf{$e_\#$} & \textbf{Time interval} & \makecell[cc]{\textbf{Topic}} \\ 
            \midrule
            1 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l} From & 2019-04-15 20:30:05 \\ To & 2019-04-15 21:30:05\end{tabular} & \textbf{díamundialdelarte, 15deabril:} enfocat(0.94), meningitis(0.94), construyendolarepública(0.94), 14deabril(0.68), ley(0.66), españa(0.62)  \\\addlinespace

            2 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l}From& 2019-04-15 09:00:05 \\ To & 2019-04-15 17:00:05\end{tabular} & \textbf{gracias:} semana(0.61), muchísimas(0.64) \\ \addlinespace
            3 & \begin{tabular}[t]{r@{:~}l}From & 2019-04-15 19:30:05 \\ To & 2019-04-16 01:00:05 \end{tabular} & \textbf{notre:} dame(0.98), catedral(0.92), incendio(0.76), parís(0.91), historia(0.73), humanidad(0.77), llamas(0.74), paris(0.64), tristeza(0.65)  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{April 15th 2019 top 3 events}
        \label{tab:mabed-impact}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Lastly, some spaces seem to be missing in the text. Are `díamundialdelarte` and `construyendolarepública` really only one word?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really liked your proposal and I think I will implement it. Yes, words are the output of an event detector and those you quoted are hashtags used by users.

Comment: @Luiscri: Thank you for the clarification. You might probabley be also interested in adding the `ragged2e` package and use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c  c  >{\RaggedRight}X }`. This way you can get rid of the large horizontal white spaces in the third column that originate from the text  being justified.

Comment: Tried using your model but spaces between rows are too wide. Also spaces between 'From' and 'To' lines. Any idea what can be failing?

Comment: @Luiscri: Did you redefine `\arraystretch` somewhere in the text of your document? This might cause the additional white space.

Comment: You were right, I had it set to 1.5 at some point on my code. However now col 1 and col 2 are aligned to the bottom of the row. How can I aling them to the top as you have it on your screenshot?

Comment: @Luiscri: Maybe adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` right after `\centering` in the table environment helps to solve the issue. However, I don't seem to be able to reproduce the alignment issue you described.

Comment: It doesn't seems to have worked.

Comment: @Luiscri: Could you pleasea show an example document? Whithout seeing what you tried, it is hard to help.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with the code I'm using right now and how it looks

Comment: If you need it I can try posting my `main.tex` as maybe a rule set there may be causing this problem. @leandriis

Comment: @Luiscri: Thaks for adding the code to your question. As far as I can see, the table contains the line `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`. This causes the table cells to not be top aligned any more. If you want the cell's contents to be top aligned, just remove this line.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Now my table looks exactly as the one you posted on your suggestion. Thank you so much for your time answering this question.